# Video blurry after Rendering in After Effects CS6

Tags: after-effects

In After Effects I edited a `1080p` video. The preview of the final composition looks fine, however the rendered output is very blurry (looks like `480p` instead of `1080p`).

Original video properties:

```
Item type: .mp4
Frame width: 1920
Framde height: 1080
Frame rate: 30.00 Fps
```

Video imported, to be sure right-click > 'Interpret Footage' > 'Main' >

```
'Conform to frame rate: 30'
'Separate Fields: off
'Remove pulldown: off'
'Pixel Aspects Ratio: Square Pixels'
```

Preview is still looking fine. Now importing that video into a new composition. Composition settings:

```
'Preset: Custom' (also tried here preset 'HDTV 1080 29.97')
'Width: 1920'
'Height: 1080'
'Pixel Aspects Ratio: Square Pixels'
'Frame Rate: 30'
'Resolution: Full'
```

Preview is still looking fine. Now File > Export > Add to Render Que.
Render settings:

```
'Quality: Best' (with 'current settings' it has the same quality loss)
'Resolution: Full'
'Size 1920x1080'
'Use comp's frame rate: 30.00'
```

Output Module settings:

```
'Format: H.264'
'Post-Render Action: None'
'Channels: RGB'
'Depth: Millions of Colors'
'Premultiplied (Matted)'
```

During the render, the preview also shows the right quality.
After the render, I open the file in VLC and there it shows poor quality. Meanwhile the same VLC player shows the original video in high quality.

Any suggestions what I miss?

Kind regards,
Igor

Comment: Is it actually blurry, or just low quality? Have you looked at the codec settings? Could be the bitrate is too low. Also, don't render to h.264 from AE, it's better to render to a lossless / intermediate codec master and run off h.264 copies from that.

Comment: Ok, that actually is the problem, it was blurry indeed. I had no knowledge about Codec settings, changed it from VBR to CBR and looked up videos on bitrate. Quality looks fine now! Thanks.